# Regular expression for a string that after a certain character can only have letters or numbers

Tags: regex

I need to ensure that a string has only letters or numbers after `#` character.

I tried this:

```
#[A-Za-z0-9_-]*
```

[image]

However as can be seen there is a match. Adding `$` at the end of the regex helped, however in my bigger program it results in no matches in a bigger regex, is there a way to do this without adding `$`? And why adding `$` made the `1 match` result disappear?

How do I do that?

Comment: You could assert a whitespace boundary at the right `#[A-Za-z0-9_-]+(?!\S)` Note that `[A-Za-z0-9_-]` also matches `_` and `-` besides letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<=#)[A-Za-z0-9_-]*
```

A look-behind ((?<=#)) is a zero-width match, so it asserts, but does not capture the match.

Comment: For a string `#asd` it returns no match

Comment: Matches for me in powershell, which language you are using, i will give a test there

Comment: I'm using https://regex101.com/. Why is a look-behind necessary in this case?